# how to make offer on items with limited time in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, discount

I have a price column the value is 500$
And
I want to update the value to 400$ for 1 day or more than 1 day after that automatically value update to 500$

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Create a new field for discounts. In this field, set the discount value. You can control the discount by your code without problem for the main amount.

Comment: can you tell me how I automatically update discount feild after update?